# Вывод 2-х минимальных и 2-х максимальных чисел PHP

Tags: php, массивы, max

Добрый день. Возможно ли из массива array(4,3,2,5,7,8,6,5,3,1,4,5,7,9) вывести сначала первое минимальное число, затем первое максимальное, затем второе минимальное и, соответственно, второе максимальное чтоб вывод был

2, 8, 1, 9

именно в таком порядке. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код писать думаю смысла нет, а вот почитать документацию можно.

1. [max](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.max.php)
2. [min](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.min.php)
3. [array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)
4. [unset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php)

Comment: большое спасибо за unset

Comment: Нет проблем, всегда приятно почитать документацию :) Еще можно почитать про функцию [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php), если хотите сделать решение универсальным.